# Receive custom protocol events in webview Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, webview, browser, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I am working with a WebView in a Windows 8.1 xaml app and need to handle navigation to a custom protocol ie. "sms://12345".

I am not able to receive NavigationStarting event.

The same thing when tried in Windows Phone 8 is working. I am anle to get events in NavigationStarting event.

The webview contains this html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

 <a href="hello:+91999999999"><img border="0" alt="" src="http://img.com/gif ></a>
</html>
```

How to capture the custom protocols in Windows phone 8.1. i know we can specify custom protocols, but I am building a Windows Phone Class Library. Any ideas??